# Toggle Input Select from Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, select, input

is there a way to call the event of toggling `<select>` input from javascript?

I want to create the behavior of `<select>` on mobile, because it has built-in user interface of an overlay (see Chrome) or a roulette (see Safari on iPhone), when you toggle the `<select>` from mobile browser. But the problem is the `<select>` button has an ugly interface. I want to make a normal button that will call the `<select>` from Javascript. Preferably an Angular way, not the jQuery way.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding you well, just firing "click" event on your select object should open/close it